# Modelling of calendar and events based on it

Tags: c++, stl, calendar, modeling

I have already programmed a football manager game some years ago with a lot functionality (Sent it to Gamestar for free publishing but was rejected because of copyrights).

I have one section in the game on that I am not really satisfied because I have no clue what would be the best fit to model it.

I have a vector of pairs for all days of one calendar year:

`std::vector<std::pair<Competition*, TDate>> year_plan;`

E.g. there can be following entries inside pointing to a Competion class instance and a date:

**CHAMPIONS_LEAGUE_DRAW, 12.03.2022**

**CHAMPIONS_LEAGUE, 15.03.2022**

**FIRST_LEAGUE, 19.03.2022**

**SECOND_LEAGUE, 19.03.2022**

--> As you can see, there can be several competitions at the same day!

The program logic is just processing the `year_plan` date by date and takes the action required on the specific competition on simulating results or simulating the draws. This perfectly works, but somehow it  does not feel right this way.

For that reason I have two questions on that:

1. Would it not make more sense to have a one year Calendar class and instances for every Competion occurence in it? (One instance per day is not enough because of having soemtimes more than one competitions per day). This would also allow to store additional information in the instance like counter for the matchday, round etc.
2. The Competitions I currently have are LeagueCompetions, CupCompetitions, Draws. All these three competitions types have some parts in common but need also special class members and methods. Draw competitions need much less information to be stored. As I need to store the Competition in the Calendar vector / class, I need somehow one class forr all three competition types. Should I use here inheritance approach even I need a specialization of the classes in addition to the common parts?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions
Mauro

Comment: Thanks Ole, all the tags are correct, still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I programmed C++ in the 1990s, but never same around to STL, `vector`, `pair` and `TDate`. I do hope someone with a more up-to-date understanding will pop by (giving the correct tags should increase the chances).

Comment: This is more related to the modelling itself. As said, I have already a solution but that seems not to be the best one. I would be also happy when you could me an advise based on your experience.

Comment: I don’t have anything to add as a comment here. I’d enjoy meeting with you at a whiteboard and maybe you could teach me something about football and/or about newer development of the C++ libraries, and I could teach you something about inheritance and design patterns. But this format is unsuited, sorry.